# where to write else condition inside loop within another loop?

Tags: php

If the phone number matches , I am able to print "Yes". If it doesnot match , i need to print "No". But if i include else part , its executing only else part. Please guide me how and where to write else part.

```
<?php  if($re['phone_v'] == "1"){
                    echo "Yes";
                }else if($re['phone_v'] == "0"){
                        for($i=0;$i < count($crusers);$i++) {
                            if ($re['phone'] == $crusers[$i]['phone']) {
                                echo "Yes";
                            }
                        }
                }
            ?>
```

I am checking condition inside table in view. small thing is making complicated.

Comment: use `elseif` instead `else if` in php syntax

Comment: @Tarang That makes no difference.

Answer (score 2):

This will help you.

```
$re['phone_v'] = 0;
$re['phone'] = 1;
$crusers[0]['phone'] = 1;
if($re['phone_v'] == "1"){
    echo "Yes";
}else{ 
if($re['phone_v'] == "0")                    
  {
      for($i=0;$i < count($crusers);$i++) 
      {
              if ($re['phone'] == $crusers[$i]['phone']) 
              {
                              echo "Yes11";
              }else{
                              echo "No";
              }
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: What’s the difference…?

Comment: He has not used curly braces after his else part in line 3.

Comment: That doesn’t make any difference. `else if {...}` is the same logic as `else { if {...} }`.

Comment: @deceze I tried with this also...whatever i do , i am able to print "Yes"..but if the condition fails, i need to print "No"...Its displaying blank value instead of "No"..

Comment: @vaishu Well, there's no `echo 'No'` anywhere…

Comment: i wrote in my system..its not working so i asked for help...now i stored the value in variable and i achieved it..